# AndEngine: edit elasticity on action

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I'm making a game for Android with AndEngine.

It's going quite well, but now I'm stuck on something. 
My main character has a elasticity set in its fixturedef so it bounces around throughout the game.
Now i want the user to be able to not let the player bounce when he does a control.

So my question: how can I modify the elasticity of my character? Because I saw you can adjust the setDensity and setFriction, but I cant see the setElasticity....

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I also up vote your question because I also have to search for this thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following way you can change the restitution or elasticity of any body in box2d.

```
ArrayList<Fixture> fixtureList = body.getFixtureList();
    for (Fixture fixture : fixtureList)
        fixture.setRestitution(0.5f);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because elasticity is expressed as a coeficient of **restitution**. Look for `setRestitution (float restitution)`.